# Expand command stored in 'tuple'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In Bash, how can I expand a command stored as a 'tuple' in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD=/my/cmd

DEV=/dev/loop

for setting in "${CMD} option1 option2 ${DEV}","SETTING1: yes" \
                   "${CMD} option1 ${DEV}","SETTING2: 0x01" ; do
    OLDIFS="${IFS}"
    IFS=","
    set -- $setting;
    echo $1 and $2

    #How do I expand this correctly to run the command stored in ${1}?  
    ${1}

    #... checking output using value stored in ${2}

    IFS="${OLDIFS}"

fi
```

Currently, the shell will interpret ${1} as several commands separated by space, so I just get a bunch of "no such file or directory"

Comment: does `eval "$1"` work for you ?

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) first, then rethink your question.

Comment: eval "${1}" does work. However it certainly comes with it's security issues so it was not a good fit in this case. I ended up following the advice from the FAQ 050 and reworked the code to another form.